# How to load raster data with hyperlink path in ArcGIS MXD?

Tags: python, raster, arcgis-10.1, hyperlink

I have a problem/question and hopefully someone of you is able to help me:

I have thousands of georeferenced raster files which have corresponding polygons (outer borders of rasters) with a hyperlink in the attribute table to open them in an image viewer. Now I want to load a raster (through selection or whatever) directly with the hyperlink into an MXD Document.

One possibility is:

```
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management("G:\\TIFF\RasterXY.tif", "Test")
```

But now I have only a temporal layer which does not really fit my needs... Maybe someone of you has an idea/solution how to solve this problem.

---

I tried some things but without any success... Here is my code till now:

```
import arcpy
data = "Polygone_31-4493"
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(data, "location")
     for row in rows:
     cursor_path = row.getValue("location")
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(data, "location")
     rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(data, "image")
     for row in rows:
     cursor_image = row.getValue("image")
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(cursor_path, cursor_image)
```

Maybe you have some ideas for this.

---

After several tries I don't think I will work. Maybe someone has another idea how to do this.

```
fc = "Shapefile"
path = "location"
image = "image"

path = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (path))]
image = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, (image))]

# Enconding the 'u
new_path = [str(item) for item in path]
new_image = [str(item) for item in image]

arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(new_path, new_image)
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6198, in MakeRasterLayer
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: This sounds like a use case for writing a Python Add-in - are you using ArcGIS 10.1?  Also, when you say "I have only a temporal layer which does not really fit my needs" can you expand upon what you mean by a temporal layer and how this does not meet your needs, please?

Comment: This is a use case for a Python Add-in. Okay forget about the temporal layer thing I understood something wrong. The code above works for me but now I have to include the hyperlink field into the code.

Comment: Maybe it helps to give you an insight into my workaround: I have polygons with their outer borders. Based on this borders i use the Identify Tool to identify interesting images in the area of interest. Then I take a lot at each image in an image viewer with the hyperlink. Now I would like to add an interesting image/images to the map document.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS 10.1?  If so, then your bit of code, coupled with a search cursor to read the field value, substituted into the onClick method is virtually the same as the example used for [**Creating a Python add-in button**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p0000001z000000)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes I'm using ArcGIS 10.1. At the moment I'm not very familiar with python and search cursors etc. but I will try it. Thanks again!

Comment: It's late here now so I'll look back in on this in a day or two to see how you got on.  I only wrote my first Python plug-in a few days ago and was surprised how easy it was - but I do have a reasonable amount of ArcPy/Python behind me now.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have it and it is pretty easy :)

```
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("shapefile")
for path in cursor:
    arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(path.getValue("location"), path.getValue("image"))
```